# Amazon FireTV get name of device

Tags: java, android, sdk, leanback, amazon-fire-tv

im currently developing an android app for the firetv cube.
Im a bit stuck in how to get the amazon fire tv device name.

I mean the "calling" name of the device like "Exeu's FireTV Cube".
Simply the name which you can configure in your device settings.

Is there any way of getting this?

Currently i can just get some Hardware Device Infos through:

```
Build.MODEL + Build.HOST + Build.PRODUCT
```